# Convert variable in Prolog

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I have a program which result is a term `equal(add(num(2),var(x)),num(3))`. Basically that term is a conversion from statement 2+x = 3. I wish to parse that term to a CLP term so I can have result like `x = 1`.

How do I assign variable to term var, such that if there is another x in the term, it can bind to same variable, e.g., `equal(add(num(2),var(x)),add(num(3),var(x),var(y))` which is same as 2 + x = 3+x+y
I expect the answer will be y = -1

Comment: A lot depends upon how you are processing `equal`, but the way you have it should work fine. If you have `var(x)` and are consistent, there's nothing wrong with that. So, ` add(A,B) = add(num(2),var(x)), add(C,D,E) = add(num(3),var(x),var(y)), D = B.` will be true.

Answer (score 0):

not sure this is exactly what you want, anyway get_var/2 could be useful to you.

```
apply_fdx(X, KV) :-
           setof(K, get_var(X, K), Ks),
           pairs_keys_values(KV, Ks, Vs),
           Vs ins -100 .. 100,
           make_fdx(X, KV, FDx),
           FDx,
           label(Vs).

get_var(X, K) :- X =.. [var,K].
get_var(X, K) :- X =.. [_|As], member(E, As), get_var(E, K).

make_fdx(equal(L,R), KV, Lf #= Rf) :-
    make_fdx(L, KV, Lf), make_fdx(R, KV, Rf).
make_fdx(add(A, B), KV, Af + Bf) :-
    make_fdx(A, KV, Af),
    make_fdx(B, KV, Bf).
make_fdx(add(A, B, C), KV, Af + Bf + Cf) :-
    make_fdx(A, KV, Af),
    make_fdx(B, KV, Bf),
    make_fdx(C, KV, Cf).
make_fdx(var(K), KV, V) :- memberchk(K-V, KV).
make_fdx(num(N), _, N).
```

yields

```
?- apply_fdx(equal(add(num(2),var(x)),add(num(3),var(x),var(y))), Vs).
Vs = [x- -100, y- -1] ;
Vs = [x- -99, y- -1] .
```

etc etc.

If you could start with a normalized syntax tree (i.e. add with 2 arguments instead of 3), make_fdx/3 could be made simpler.

Comment: You can simplify this by removing all the setof and getvar stuff and the `Vs ins ...` line, moving the pairs_keys_values/3 just before label/1, and changing the penultimate clause to `make_fdx(var(K), KV, V) :- memberchk(K-V, KV), V ins -100..100.`